# Trying to understand promise using q library; .then on resolve doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

New to NodeJS, trying to implement a REST based authentication, after which I need to get the auth token to use in subsequent requests. Trying to do this using promises in nodejs (using the q library).

The getData() function is executed first before authentication could complete, but I thought this is what the promise framework guaranteed. I could be completely wrong here, so hoping for some help.

Looking through all the tutorials and docs, there are so many flavours of implementation, it is difficult to see what is the right way to do it.

```
var request = require("request");
var q = require('q');

var options = { method: 'POST',
url: 'https://somewebsite.com:8080/auth',
headers:
    { 'postman-token': '33e52c21-22cf-1571-c082-3b612d62e5c1',
        'cache-control': 'no-cache',
        cookie: 'sails.sid=s%3AuBo1j-iEEd0IFanmW4eJ7HxKO6D8ZWVm.ViK%2Bx8koYIPdqnGyrkRAMrtb8lBR8Xry9f8CcfaEfVM',
        'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6',
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        referer: 'https://avrij.eyesover.com/',
        'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        authorization: 'Bearer undefined',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36',
        origin: 'somewebsite.com',
        accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*' },
body: '{"username":"John","password":"*********"}' };

    var options1 = { method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://somewebsite.com:8080/getData',
      headers:
    { 'postman-token': 'dcc618ef-6382-95cd-dbce-49c8ac761589',
        'cache-control': 'no-cache',
        cookie: 'sails.sid=s%3AuBo1j-iEEd0IFanmW4eJ7HxKO6D8ZWVm.ViK%2Bx8koYIPdqnGyrkRAMrtb8lBR8Xry9f8CcfaEfVM',
        'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6',
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch, br',
        referer: 'https://somewebsite.com/',
        authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36',
        origin: 'https://somewebsite.com',
        accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*' } };

    var token = null;

    function authenticate() {

     var deferred = q.defer();

     request(options, function (error, response, body) {
     if (error) throw new Error(error);

       console.log("Authentication Done! - see response below")
       console.log(body)

       token = body.token;

       deferred.resolve(token);

      });

     return deferred.promise;
   }

   function getData(token){

     var deferred = q.defer();

     console.log("Here is the token we got " + token);
     console.log("Now that authenticated, lets get some data");

     request(options1, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) throw new Error(error);


       console.log("Here is all the data received!")
       console.log(body);
       deferred.resolve();

      });
    return deferred.promise;

    }

    authenticate()
       .then( getData(token));
```

The results I get is:

```
    Here is the token we got null
    Now that authenticated, lets get some data
    Here is all the data received!
    {
      "err": "Invalid Token!"
    }
    Authentication Done! - see response below
   {
     "user": {
     "username": "John",
     "email": "info@info.com",
     "permissions": [
     "editSetup",
     "userManagement"
      ],
    "role": [
    "ROLE_LIMITED"
    ],
    "createdAt": "2017-01-12T01:18:29.403Z",
    "updatedAt": "2017-03-27T16:45:53.047Z",
    "id": "*********"
    },
    "token": "AKDL879ASD879ASD098DAS09cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjU4NzZkOTY1ZmIzMTQwZDQwNDIwNGY2MiIsImlhdCI6MTQ5MTQASDADAS90899767ASD8TQwfQ.VC1suru9CCLz0VmlqwFrOwAS0980DA90S90S8DA0S"
    }
```

Comment: you're using .then wrong ... `.then(getData(token))` should be `.then(getData)` - any `.then` argument(s) that are NOT a function are ignored

Comment: Also, appreciate if you have any recommendation on online courses that I could take to learn NodeJS, and the MEAN stack. It is important for me to be able to ask questions to understand rather than just follow videos without context.

Comment: @Jaromanda: Thank you.. this is my first post on StackOverflow, and blown over by how quick I got a response.

Comment: @Jaromanda if I follow your suggest, how can I pass the token value to the getData function?

Comment: Btw, you shouldn't `throw new Error(error);`, you should `deferred.reject(new Error(error)); return;`

Comment: So the code already is working, in that it is executing in sequence, but now the second function is not able to see the token.

how do I access the token variable inside the second function if I am not passing it ?

Comment: when I removed the token declaration, I am getting an error that token in the getData function is undefined.

Assuming that the body.token is passed to the getData function, how can I refer to it inside getData ?

can I do something like this.value? would value hold the body.token?

Comment: @all: Yes, I will implement the deferred.reject instead of throwing the error

Comment: I have my updated code here: https://jsfiddle.net/t865uw3h/1/

still getting the error: 

authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
                                       ^

ReferenceError: token is not defined

Comment: @Jaromanda: Can you advise why I might be getting the above error?

Comment: btw.. here are my dependencies, from the package.json file:

  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.16.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.0",
    "ejs": "~2.5.5",
    "express": "~4.14.1",
    "morgan": "~1.7.0",
    "node-rest-client": "^3.1.0",
    "q": "^1.5.0",
    "request": "^2.81.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.2"
  }
}

Comment: it does exist in the code, but I missed while copying:

updated it here: https://jsfiddle.net/t865uw3h/2/

Comment: @JaromandaX you got the problem, when I print the body.token where I resolve, I get "undefined" as the value.